# Smooth scroll won't work, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The issue is I have a web page with a anchor, I want to scroll smoothly to it. So I looked around on-line and found this code.

```
//dezinerfolio
eval((function(){a="Scroller={speed:10,8dC.;d.while(dC.+C.}} J8N;d=5;&&M4M}d&&dM4dM}%4%} 0J8a,F4(F,fa@7a.4a.LP+F7Jend8e66.cancelBubble=true;6.Value=fa@;}&&(E(7J8di=Hner3||5.G3;hN.3;a=(Ed>ah-d>i7e@{-(h-d)7}e@{a=a+(d-a}To(0,aEa==a}=aJHit8KwHdow,A,A7,A82P;l=9;d=locatiP;D&&D.HdexOfL#)!=-1&&(l/+l=C)Kl,Gck,endEl.PGck=2l=this.hash.substr(1E9.name==l;i=setILL+(9)+),107}}}}}};Hit()",b=48;while(b>=0)a=a.replace(new RegExp("%23456789@ACDEFGHJKLMNP".charAt(b),"g"),("\042Scroller.entfunction(offsetParscrollwindow.returndocumattachEvntervala=.getElemsByTagName(a);if(offsetTop){for(i=0;i<a.length;i++.pathnamea+=Math.ceil((d-ae.stopPropagationTopa.addEvListenerbody)/speede.prevDefaultclearI(i)pageYOffsetend(this);Height .Elemev)}:a[i]lseload=dl.href);b,dcliin},((.=.=C||on".split(""))[b--]);return a})())
```

So this works on all of my websites, so I believed it would work on my new site, BUT it did not work. Can anyone see why not???

This is the HTML

```
<head>
<script src="smooth.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> Scroller.speed=7; </script>
</head>
```

Then

```
<body>
<a href="#bottom" id="down1" class="down" style="display:block"></a>
```

Then about half way down the page.

```
<a name="bottom" id="bottom"></a>
</body>
```

This is the CSS for the link.

```
#down1 {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:50%;
top:50%;
cursor: url(d.png), auto;
z-index:99;
}
```

So I know this does work, because I have seen it work on other sites. But not sure what the issue is???

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Ouch! Whereever you found this one, throw it away and use one without eval.

Comment: Can you see any Error in console?

Comment: No I don't get any errors, just it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend not using that script and using jQuery. This can be done very easily with jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#bottom" id="down1" class="down" style="display:block"></a>
  ....
  <a name="bottom" id="bottom"></a>
  <!-- load jquery however you like I will load from Google CDN -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Document ready shorthand statement
    $(function() {
      // Select link by id and add click event
      $('#down1').click(function() {

        // Animate Scroll to #bottom
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#bottom").offset().top }, // Tell it to scroll to the top #bottom
          1000 // How long scroll will take in milliseconds
        );

        // Prevent default behavior of link
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Ok found the problem with your code, it is your css. In your css you have

```
html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

change that to this:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Also there is an easier way to write your jQuery so that it is less code.

first you will need to restructure your HTML a little

In your link section change the href of you links to the the id of the div you want them to link to, for example:

```
<a href="#Portfoilio" class="link" id="down1" class="down" style="display:block"></a>
```

would change to:

```
<a href="#bottom" id="down1" class="down link" style="display:block"></a>
```

also you will see i added a second class "link". This is so we can target each with one jQuery call.

and your jQuery at bottom would change to this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Document ready shorthand statement
    $(function() {
      $('.link').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(id).offset().top }, 'slow');
        // Prevent default behavior of link
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Here is a link to how i change your HTML and jQuery:
http://pastebin.com/0LfyjNLx

Comment: Thank you for the script but it still doesn't seem to work, clicking on the link has no effect? Unless I remove return false, in which case it just jumps down. Not sure why it doesn't work? Any ideas? But thank you very much for the help so far, **I really appreciate the help.**

Comment: Does this have any browser limitations, as I mainly use Chrome, which doesn't work, but Firefox does. Is there a way to make this more compatible.

Comment: If you look here it works in every browser: http://jsbin.com/ogutil/1 Might be something with your implementation. Paste your code above and I can help

Comment: If you really need help I would gladly help you outside of this site view my profile and goto my site and submit the form with your info

Comment: This is where I am using it williamchanter.co.uk it doesn't work in anything other than Firefox, see what you think???

Comment: Ok i found your error and edited the post above with fix and a few recommendations

Comment: That is Fantastic, **Thank you** It now works in them all. I just have one more issue, when I remove `html` from the CSS it styles wrong in Firefox and Opera, I am not sure what to do to fix this. If you could have a look and see what you think that would be great. But thank you for all your help so far, it has been great. **Thanks**

Comment: Put HTML back into where you took it away then remove the overflow-x: hidden out and into its own on the body. Hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super-simple way to do the smooth scrolling. Use jQuery and the jQuery.localScroll plugin.

Download the latest smoothscroll.js: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll/releases

Add the two javascript references:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/smoothscroll.js"></script>
```

Then make sure to add the class "smoothScroll" to your `<a>` links, like this:

```
<a href="#anchor1" class="smoothScroll">Jump to Page Location</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple function like

```
  scrollTo(x,y){
    let x1=0
    let y1=window.scrollY
    let yDiff=y-y1
    if(yDiff>10 || yDiff<-10){
      window.scrollTo(x,y1+(yDiff/10))
     setTimeout(()=>{
       this.scrollTo(x,y,smooth)
     },10)
   }
 }
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.